# How to install gRPC python package on IoT device?

Tags: python, android, pip, package, grpc

I have an IoT device (Android device) and some python script to interact with gRPC server running on the same device (as an Android app). I've cross-compiled Python3 and in general it's working - i was able to run some python script with it from Android app (using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` and passing `PATH`, `PWD`, `PYTHONHOME`, `PYTHONPATH`, `ANDROID_DATA`, `ANDROID_ROOT` env vars).

The python script that uses gRPC looks as follows:

```
...
import gprc

...

channel = grpc.insecure_channel(url)
```

When the script is executed i get the following error:

> import error: No module named 'grpc'

Here is the structure of python directories on IoT device (that i've prepared):

```
├── bin
├── lib
│   ├── pkgconfig
│   ├── python3.9
│   │   ├── asyncio
│   │   ├── collections
│   │   ├── concurrent
│   │   ├── ctypes
│   │   ├── curses
│   │   ├── dbm
│   │   ├── distutils
│   │   ├── encodings
│   │   ├── ensurepip
│   │   ├── html
│   │   ├── http
│   │   ├── idlelib
│   │   ├── importlib
│   │   ├── json
│   │   ├── lib-dynload
│   │   ├── lib2to3
│   │   ├── logging
│   │   ├── multiprocessing
│   │   ├── pydoc_data
│   │   ├── site-packages
│   │   ├── sqlite3
│   │   ├── tkinter
│   │   ├── turtledemo
│   │   ├── unittest
│   │   ├── urllib
│   │   ├── venv
│   │   ├── wsgiref
│   │   ├── xml
│   │   └── xmlrpc
│   └── site-packages
│       ├── google
│       ├── grpc
│       ├── grpcio-1.30.0.dist-info
│       └── protobuf-3.12.2.dist-info
└── share
    ├── man
    │   └── man1
    └── terminfo
         ...
```

As you can see i've put relevant packages to `site-packages` (by just copying the same files from my mac machine to iot device which can be incorrect).

What's the right way to do it (where and what exactly should i put relevant libs to python dirs tree)? Can i put any dirs/files to the same dir where the script is (locally)? Is there any lite gRPC impl (probably with limited functionality) in python which can be easily prepared for distribution (eg. copy/pasted)?

FYI I've tried to use `python -m pip install grpcio --target` and then `python -m zipapp resources -m "grpc_serial:main"` but it's not working even locally because of module `cygrpc` not found too (but working if using `grpc` package that is installed globally):

> import error: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (../python3/lib/python3.9/grpc/_cython/**init**.py)

If i run "python -m pip install cygrpc --target resources" to have a standalone dist for cygrpc i get ~30 directories (probably transitive deps) about 50Mb which is just crazy heavy.

I can provide a `tree` output for `site-packages` if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (workaround) by using `Thrift` RPC which seems to be more lightweight on python side (it required only `thrift` and `six` deps installed locally (in the same directory)).

I guess the rootcause for non using of gRPC was not installed transitive deps (not sure it is gRPC or pip issue).